Theorems with either a default title, or a user's one
Here is a M(not)WE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keytheorems}

\newkeytheorem{mythm}[
  numbered = false,
  name     = My theorem
]
    
\begin{document}

\begin{mythm}
   Some text
\end{mythm}

\begin{mythm}[Named theorem]
   Some text
\end{mythm}

\end{document}

I would like to obtain the following output. Is there an easy way to do it?
My theorem. Some text
Named theorem. Some text


You can check if the "note" argument (#3 in headformat) is empty. Note the \protect is necessary because keytheorems fully expands the head specification.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keytheorems}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \tlIfEmptyTF \tl_if_empty:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newkeytheoremstyle{mythmsty}
  {
    headformat=\protect\tlIfEmptyTF{#3}{\NAME}{\NOTE},
    notebraces={}{},
    notefont=\bfseries,
    noteseparator={},
  }
\newkeytheorem{mythm}[
  numbered = false,
  name     = My theorem,
  style    = mythmsty,
]
    
\begin{document}

\begin{mythm}
   Some text
\end{mythm}

\begin{mythm}[Named theorem]
   Some text
\end{mythm}

\end{document}



Thanks for this tip. If I'm guessing correctly, you're the maintainer of keytheorems. If I'm right, I think your answer would be a spa example for the doc.

@projetmbc Yes I am. And yes, one of these days I will add a bunch of examples to the doc. I agree this is a useful one

Using \IfBlankTF instead of \tlIfEmptyTF seems to work.

@projetmbc Yes it would but if for some reason you wanted just a space as the title then the behavior is different. I admit this is unlikely but it's not the standard amsthm behavior
